# Integral of Difference of Logs

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, logarithms, laurent-series

[image: Question 2011/1/II/13A]

I get the expansion of $h$ to be
$$ h(z) = {1 \over z } \sum_{r=1}^{\infty}{1 \over r}{(-{\alpha \over z}})^r $$
$$ \Rightarrow h(z) = \sum_{r=-2}^{-\infty}{{(-\alpha)^{r+1} \over -(r+1)} z^{r}} $$
and thus the final integral to be $0$, since
$ \int_{|z|=2} z^n dz = 0,$
since $2 \ge 1,$ the inside boundary of the annulus.

Is this right, or am I getting something mixed up?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I've missed the "divide by $r$" (which I did have in my workings, just forgot to type in. Edited now. Thanks!

Comment: If your expression is right $h$ has a pole in $z=0$and you are asked to compute the integral on a circle surrounding it.

Comment: Indeed. And then by the Reside Theorem, that is equal to the sum of the residues (times $2 \pi i$). But $z=0$ is the only singularity (I think...) and it has residue $0$, by the Laurent expansion (since there is no $1/z$ term)... :/